# Managed Object Model initialization

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am having an issue with core data and I should note that I am using xcode 4.2. I'm getting this error when I try to run my code

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'**

I have traced it down to this line of code in the boilerplate getter given to me by xcode

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyApp" withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

Which is returning nil. Now I know I have a manged object model in my supporting files.

Things I have tried so far :

- Clean the project
- Reset Content and Settings on the Sim
- Test on a real device.
- Restart Xcode

Comment: How are you creating the persistent store coordinator?

Comment: Im using the function created by xcode when I choose to include Coredata in my application.
`- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a file called `MyApp.momd` (and case matters on the device, though not in simulator) that is included in your "Copy Resources" step? Is `modelURL` nil, or just `managedObjectModel`?

You can look in your Simulator directory to see if the file is being copied. Look in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<version>/Applications/<ID>/MyApp.app`. In Finder you would need to use "Show Package Contents" or you can go there using Terminal.

Comment: I found the .app in the terminal and there is a MyApp.momd but it is a directory. Should it be? Also the URL is not nil, the managedObjectModel is nil, so I'm thinking it has something to do with the initWithContentsOfURL method

Comment: That feels like corruption in the model. Do you get any errors in the log?

Comment: Wow the error was in there. 

2011-08-25 19:42:32.414 cdtool_Sim[7054:7b03] failed to compile model with failure reason Unable to parse the format string "SELECT * FROM Bet"

warning: Version hash information not available for all models


I used an incorrect format for a predicate. Thanks so much for the help!